# Extarct data from json array in python for Excel

Tags: python, json, excel

```
{
  "result" : [{
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 0.300000,
      "start" : 0.000000,
      "word" : "bright"
    }, {
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 0.720000,
      "start" : 0.330000,
      "word" : "bright"
    }, {
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 1.950000,
      "start" : 1.710000,
      "word" : "bright"
    }],
  "text" : "bright bright bright"
}
```

I have this JSON array with me. I need to extract all the details from the "result" in the table format. For example,

```
   conf       start      end        word
1.000000    0.000000   0.300000    bright
1.000000    0.330000   0.720000    bright
1.000000    1.710000   1.950000    bright
```

How can I extract these values from the "result" part and append the details in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) built-in module.

```py
import csv

json = {
  "result" : [{
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 0.300000,
      "start" : 0.000000,
      "word" : "bright"
    }, {
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 0.720000,
      "start" : 0.330000,
      "word" : "bright"
    }, {
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 1.950000,
      "start" : 1.710000,
      "word" : "bright"
    }],
  "text" : "bright bright bright"
}

header = json['result'][0].keys()
with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as file_:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(file_, fieldnames=header)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(json['result'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

json_val = {
  "result" : [{
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 0.300000,
      "start" : 0.000000,
      "word" : "bright"
    }, {
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 0.720000,
      "start" : 0.330000,
      "word" : "bright"
    }, {
      "conf" : 1.000000,
      "end" : 1.950000,
      "start" : 1.710000,
      "word" : "bright"
    }],
  "text" : "bright bright bright"
}
pd.read_json(json_val['result'], orient='index').to_csv('someName.csv')
```

Comment: I am getting an error here "TypeError: string indices must be integers". How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would very much recommend `pandas`, will not take a lot of lines.

Based on your example, this is achievable with:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.read_json(json['result'], orient='index').to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

See documentation on [how to create a dataset from a dictionary](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) and [how to export to Excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).